# MAX COUNT BY GROUP BY Retrieve only max count records

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I want to return only the max count record from the following grouping.

```
select veh_manufname,  count(*) as "Total Count"  
from offence o 
join demerit d on o.dem_code = d.dem_code 
join vehicle v on v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin 
group by veh_manufname
having sum(d.dem_points)>=2 
order by "Total count" desc, veh_manufname ;
```

This Returns:

```
Veh_manufname   Total Count
 BMW                 6
 AUDI                6
 TATA                5
 ..                 ..
```

Ideally it should return only :

```
AUDI                6
BMW                 6
```

Sort the manufname asc by

Tried this but returns the same:

```
select veh_manufname, max(TOTAL_COUNT)
FROM (
select veh_manufname,  count(*) as "TOTAL_COUNT"  from offence o join demerit d on o.dem_code = d.dem_code join vehicle v 
on v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin group by veh_manufname
having sum(d.dem_points)>=2 )
GROUP BY veh_manufname
order by max(TOTAL_COUNT) desc, veh_manufname ;
```

Comment: @zealous SQL developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` or `rank` window function. Also I have removed unnecessary aggregation in the top query.

```
select 
    veh_manufname, 
    TOTAL_COUNT
FROM (
    select 
        veh_manufname,  
        count(*) as TOTAL_COUNT ,
        dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk 
    from offence o 
    join demerit d 
    on o.dem_code = d.dem_code 
    join vehicle v 
    on v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin 
    group by 
        veh_manufname
    having sum(d.dem_points)>=2 
) t
where rnk = 1
```

You can use `TOP with ties` as following

```
select 
    veh_manufname, 
    TOTAL_COUNT
FROM (
    select 
        veh_manufname,  
        count(*) as TOTAL_COUNT 
    from offence o 
    join demerit d 
    on o.dem_code = d.dem_code 
    join vehicle v 
    on v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin 
    group by 
        veh_manufname
    having sum(d.dem_points)>=2 
) t
order by 
    TOTAL_COUNT desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Comment: @Emma provided you second option, let me know if it works.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-count.php Something like the second example.

Comment: Can you help me without using the rank?

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected at line 2